# How does GHC really handle versioning?

Tags: haskell, dependencies, ghc, cabal

We – *haskellers* – might all know what **cabal hell** is. When trying to upgrade our application / library, we get a failure because of different versions installed and upper bounds that don’t match.

I don’t get it. I checked: GHC installs packages as versionned. That means when you install `mtl` for instance, you have several folders for `mtl`, one per version installed. That sounds great, because we could install several versions of the same package, and depending on our upper bounds in our `.cabal`, we could select the versions we’d like to use.

However, in a lot of cases, GHC doesn’t work that way. If you have an upper bound, like `mtl < 4.2`, you won’t be able to install `mtl-4.2` or upper. And I don’t get why. Why cabal/ghc doesn’t say “Yeah, I can install that, it doesn’t break anything actually, because the project uses a version I already have, so I’ll just keep using that version”?

I guess there’s a good reason for that, and maybe that’s because of concurrent versions. If you use `mtl-4.2` and you depend on a package that uses `mtl-4.1`, you’d need two versions at the same time, which mustn’t be allowed. However, GHC could default to the lower version, and allow to install upper versions without breaking anything.

Another point about that: if doing so, I guess with a lot of versions, it’ll be hard to track which versions we are *really* using. Is there a way to check that? I sometimes use the `-v3` flag to get more information about what’s going on, but something like `cabal dep-list` would be great. Maybe it already exists with `ghc-pkg`?

Comment: Work out this example: A depends on B and C; B depends on D version <1.0; C depends on D version >1.0; and A passes one of D's data structures that B returned to a function in C.  What is the right thing to do?

Comment: In that case, fail, indeed. But I have comon shared versions ranges, why doesn’t cabal pick up the higher common version?

Comment: I don't understand your most concrete example ("However, in a lot of cases, ...").  Would you be more explicit about how you faced this problem -- e.g. when doesn't ghc let you install `mtl-4.2`; where do you have the upper bound; what else are you depending on?

Comment: In my cases, I wanted to upgrade a package, `monad-control`. I also depend on `either` and `monad-journal`, both depending on `monad-control` as well. And I guess they both use the same upper bound than me, which is `<= 1.1`. When installing `monad-control`, it fails, rejecting both `either` and `monad-journal`.

Comment: I asked the same some time ago [here](/questions/25869041) and got great answers.

Comment: I don't really understand the question either, but in the third and fourth paragraphs (and perhaps the title?), you are talking about functionality that belongs to Cabal, not GHC.

Answer (score 0):

This question has many subquestions, but I'll tackle one.

It asks: "Another point about that: if doing so, I guess with a lot of versions, it’ll be hard to track which versions we are really using. Is there a way to check that? I sometimes use the -v3 flag to get more information about what’s going on, but something like cabal dep-list would be great. Maybe it already exists with ghc-pkg?"

If you run within a sandbox, which other elements of this question seem to imply you do, then you can call `cabal sandbox hc-pkg list` to see the sandbox environment, and generally use `cabal sandbox hc-pkg anywhere one might use`ghc-pkg`to do the other things one might do with`ghc-pkg` but sandbox-local.